# Number of Users using different TLS version

Tags: java, apache, ssl

I have a very general question how to track # of users connections that use different TLS version.
We have pretty standard Web application that use apache httpd as Application Server (version 2.3.x). I need to know general way hot to track number of sessions/users that use different TLS versions. Currently we enabled TLS 1.0, 1.1 1.2 general idea to disable TLS 1.0 but before doing it it will be good to know percentage of users who uses TLS 1.0.
Is the any good way to gather this information?

Comment: You can probably do it by analysing the clickstream log, but why do you want to disable TLS 1.0?

Comment: We want to disable TLS 1.0 because of Known vulnerabilities in this protocol like BEAST attach etc.